# CS1998: This async method lacks 'await'

Tags: async-await

We got many cs1998 code compiler bugs in our project, if I add await Task.Delay(0) in the async method will that resolve the bugs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: As a point of reference you may not want to mention a particular course name...

Answer (score 1):

> if I add await Task.Delay(0) in the async method will that resolve the bugs?

Maybe. CS1998 is a warning, which means the code is *probably* wrong. In this case, the methods will run synchronously. If that's the desired behavior, then there's no bug, and I recommend avoiding it via `#pragma` (not `await Task.Delay(0);`). If you want the code to be asynchronous, then the code has a bug: it's not asynchronous.